# Differential Equation with complex non-constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

I have the following equation which I am trying to solve:
$$
R''(r) + 1/r · R'(r) + i·K(r)·R'(r) + G(r)·R(r) + i·F(r)·R(r) =0
$$
I want to solve this differential equation for $R(r)$. All the other functions are known and $i$ is the imaginary unit. Is it correct to say that the following equations must be satisfied simultaneously?
$$
R''(r)+1/r· R(r) + G(r)·R(r)=0\text{ and }K(r)·R'(r) + F(r)·R(r)=0 
$$
In this way, I can substitute $R'(r)$ from the second equation into the first one.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not true: $R(r)$ is going to be complex, even if $K$, $G$ and $F$ are real, so that will mix up the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: So in order to use the method that I mentioned, a possible solution would be to write $R(r)=|R(r)|e^{(i \theta)}$ and then write the equations for the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: It's hardly ever helpful to separate real and imaginary parts when trying to solve a differential equation in closed form.  Deal with a complex quantity as a whole rather than trying to break it up.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way to deal with this equation (given the nature of the other functions that I have) is to use power series; I could not find any other analytical method. That is why I am also looking for any alternatives. Unless I solve it numerically, I will use Forbenius method instead.